# Autolayout a view within a view

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I'm trying to have auto layout for my ios application but for iphone 6s the border is too small I've tried using pin and alignment constraints but it doesnt look right. The iphone 6s plus looks fine though. The only problem I have is the iphone 6s. The third image is what I have right now which is the view has is horizontal and vertical in container.

[image]

Comment: You need to specify your constraints to troubleshoot.

Comment: My constraints I have just have is the view has horizontal and vertical in container and that's it

Comment: I see only one image. Did you mean to post 3?

Comment: This is the other image that has the storyboard right now. [Other image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQJ3L.png)

Comment: You could minimize the amount of auto layout that you have to do by simply using 3 vertically-oriented `UIStackView`s that each contain a horizontally-oriented `UIStackView` (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using fixed dimensions for the cells and the inter-cell spacing. Using a `UICollectionView` is probably overkill for this example, because you'll *always* have 9 squares for Tic-Tac-Toe. If that's the case, then you can do the following, assuming that the squares are `UIButton`s and they're contained in a plain `UIView`:

- Constrain one cell's height and width to be 1/3rd the view's height and width. You can do this in the storyboard by adding height and width constraints that are equal to the superview's, but with a multiplier of 0.33.
- Constrain all other cells' heights and widths to be equal to cell #1's.
- For the borders, use User Defined Runtime Attributes to add a border, like this:
  [image]